# Parented Object Flying away when moving

Tags: animation, parent

I'm trying to animate a[image] simple robot and some objects are flying away when moving controller. I was trying to clear and set location/size/scale. Don't know how to fix it. Pls help.

Comment: It's most likely there's a circular dependency in your setup. I.e A bone or object (lets call it Bone A) is parented to a chain that contains a bone that is parented back to bone A (Hence the name 'circular dependency'). This is why ROOT bones are particularly useful. A Root bone has no parent and you can safely parent controller or target bones to it without running into this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a transformation issue.

1. select all relevant objects
2. Unlink them (<kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>P</kbd>)
3. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> then *Apply > All Transforms*
4. Parent the objects again

Comment: i've tried, but nope. That's not it.